# Failed to install ta-lib

Tags: python, installation, pip, ta-lib

I tried to install ta-lib, but only to fail.

How can I solve this problem? Here goes my terminal error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 clang-4.0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
 clang-4.0: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
 error: command 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang' failed with exit status 254
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the full error traceback?